# Delete a file uploaded in Google App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5

```
deleteImageServingUrl
```

How can I use deleteImageServingUrl to delete an uploaded file from the GAE.

```
 if (getenv('APP_ENGINE_ENVIRONMENT') == 'PRODUCTION') {
                $bucket = getenv('PRODUCTION_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME');
            } else {
                $bucket = getenv('TESTING_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME');
            }
    $root_path = 'gs://' . $bucket . '/';
    $file_name = 'post_attachments_34-Funny-Duck-Dancing-Picture.jpg';
    $root_path .= $file_name;
    $delete_image = CloudStorageTools::deleteImageServingUrl($root_path);
```

Comment: What's the problem? Any error or something from that code?

Comment: I didn't get either errors or output